# Bigger Notification Bar?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, notification-bar

Is there a way to make the Notification Bar thicker?

I recently bought [this case](http://store.androidcentral.com/trident-kraken-series-cases/4A104A7899A.htm) and it makes it incredibly hard to pull down the notification bar.

I was wondering if there was a way to thicken the notification bar, without completely hacking the phone?

I have a Motorola Droid X

Comment: I recommend telling the makers of the case about your problem -- hopefully they'll fix it and you might get a free one.

Comment: You know, silly me, I hadn't thought of that. I'll see if I can contact their customer service dept. I doubt they'll change the case though... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a launcher like LauncherPro or ADW Launcher, you can just hit the menu button in any homescreen and click NOTIFICATIONS. That however doesn't help if you're in another app and want to bring down the Notification area, unfortunately.

In LP, you can also configure a swipe action to pull down the Notification area.

There's also [HelloStatusBar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/hellostatusbar/jp.androdev.hellostatusbar) which is an app that when clicked will bring down the bar. One workaround maybe to launch it and then while in another app, long-press HOME to make it show in the recently used app list.

If it works, I would recommend [exsbar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/exsbar/com.matsumo.exsbar) which allows you to assign the long-press search button or long-press camera button to this function.

Comment: Note: in ADW, by default, swiping down in the desktop will open the notification area

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to modify the core files in android in order to do that.

Comment: dang it, I figured that's what would have to happen... openHome or an application like that wouldn't help either would it?

Comment: I don't think openHome would work, no.  You might be able to get an app that triggers the notification bar to drop down somehow, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think so. Guess I'll just have to write one :) Thanks!